# Resizing WPF Grid Column when other Columns children is collapsed?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have two controls in a `Grid`,and need to make one to fill all the `Grid` space after the another one get `Collapseded`,i don't know what `Container` can i use,i tried `StackPanel` and `DockPanel` too,but  i couldn't find a good solution.here's my code:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding Istxt1Visible}"/>
 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding Istxt2Visible}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This way the _grid is resized to the size of the text boxes._ Single line text boxes cannot expand in height. You should make them multiline and also you should fix the size of the grid in some way (Stretching to the parent, or a fixed height).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about using a converter? Such as

in Window resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:VisibilityToColumnLengthConverter x:Key="visConv" />
</Window.Resources>
```

.....

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource visConv}}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=tb2, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource visConv}}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Visibility="collapsed" Name="tb1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible"   Name="tb2" />
    </Grid>
```

Finally the code of the converter is

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Windows.Visibility), typeof(System.Windows.GridLength))]
public class VisibilityToColumnLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object  Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Windows.Visibility vis = (System.Windows.Visibility)value;

        if (vis == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            return new System.Windows.GridLength(1, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
        else
            return new System.Windows.GridLength(1, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Auto);
    }

    public object  ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Klaus78 :Thanx but,they both can be `Visible` or `collapsed`.I edited the question!