# How can I create a 2x2 grid in WPF that resizes when elements change visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a grid with two columns and two rows in WPF. I want the grid to resize in a special kind of way depending on which cells are visible, I've made some illustrations to better explain:

Case 1: One item is visible - one cell fills all available space

[image]

Case 2; Two items are visible - space is divided between rows

[image]

Case 3: Three items are visible - row 2 is split in two columns

[image]

Case 4: All four items are visible - Space is distributed evenly

[image]

This post: [Resizing WPF Grid Column when other Columns children is collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286029/resizing-wpf-grid-column-when-other-columns-children-is-collapsed)

Describes how to solve my problem for a single row using a visibility to size converter, but in order to make it work for two rows i would have to bind the size of one row to the visibility of two elements. This might be possible using a multibinding, but i'm not sure if that would be the best approach. Maybe there is a better way of doing this rather than using a grid at all?

Comment: Should it be possible that row 1 has 2 columns and row 2 only 1 column?

Comment: I only need the cases shown above, so that would not be necessary.

Comment: Just to be sure: in case 1, 2 or 3 it does not matter which of your four items aren't visible?

Comment: No, it does not matter.

Comment: Come to think of it, it does not have to depend on visibility. I don't need to have all four items there at all time if that simplifies the solution somehow

Comment: I thought about using a WrapPanel instead of a Grid but the problem is in case 3 you would have 2 items in the first row and 1 in the second.

Comment: That would work. It doesn't matter too much if case 3 is inverted like that.

Comment: I've been trying to use a wrap panel, but i don't believe there is a way to say that there should only be two elements in the first row, meaning i would have trouble with resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a fun problem. Basically you want to encapsulate the notion of a movable item in a class so you can easily bind the Grid props to something programmable. In my thinking, I created a type `Cell` for this. Now you can bind all the props to one object when you want the layout moved around. You'll see 4 methods in the view-model: `ShowAllCells`, `Show3Cells`, etc. which are what you would call based on your presentation logic. Think this pretty much does it.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="{Binding Cell1.Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Cell1.Col}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Cell1.ColSpan}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Cell1.RowSpan}" Visibility="{Binding Cell1.Vis}" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="{Binding Cell2.Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Cell2.Col}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Cell2.ColSpan}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Cell2.RowSpan}" Visibility="{Binding Cell2.Vis}" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="{Binding Cell3.Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Cell3.Col}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Cell3.ColSpan}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Cell3.RowSpan}" Visibility="{Binding Cell3.Vis}" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="{Binding Cell4.Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Cell4.Col}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Cell4.ColSpan}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Cell4.RowSpan}" Visibility="{Binding Cell4.Vis}" />
</Grid>
```

**View-Model & Cell**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int row;

        public int Row
        {
            get { return row; }
            set
            {
                if (row == value) return;
                row = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(@"Row");
            }
        }

        private int col;

        public int Col
        {
            get { return col; }
            set
            {
                if (col == value) return;
                col = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(@"Col");
            }
        }

        private int rowSpan;

        public int RowSpan
        {
            get { return rowSpan; }
            set
            {
                if (rowSpan == value) return;
                rowSpan = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(@"RowSpan");
            }
        }

        private int colSpan;

        public int ColSpan
        {
            get { return colSpan; }
            set
            {
                if (colSpan == value) return;
                colSpan = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(@"ColSpan");
            }
        }

        private Visibility vis;

        public Visibility Vis
        {
            get { return vis; }
            set
            {
                if (vis == value) return;
                vis = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(@"Vis");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel 
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Cell1 = new Cell();
            Cell2 = new Cell();
            Cell3 = new Cell();
            Cell4 = new Cell();

            // Call the one you want. 
            ShowAllCells();
            Show3Cells(Cell2, Cell3, Cell4, Cell1);
            Show2Cells(Cell2, Cell3, Cell4, Cell1);
            Show1Cell(Cell2, Cell3, Cell4, Cell1);
        }

        private void ShowAllCells()
        {
            Cell1.Row = 0;
            Cell1.Col = 0;
            Cell1.RowSpan = 1;
            Cell1.ColSpan = 1;
            Cell1.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
            Cell2.Row = 0;
            Cell2.Col = 1;
            Cell2.RowSpan = 1;
            Cell2.ColSpan = 1;
            Cell2.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
            Cell3.Row = 1;
            Cell3.Col = 0;
            Cell3.RowSpan = 1;
            Cell3.ColSpan = 1;
            Cell3.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
            Cell4.Row = 1;
            Cell4.Col = 1;
            Cell4.RowSpan = 1;
            Cell4.ColSpan = 1;
            Cell4.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Show3Cells(Cell one, Cell two, Cell three, Cell hidden1)
        {
            one.Row = 0;
            one.Col = 0;
            one.RowSpan = 1;
            one.ColSpan = 2;
            one.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
            two.Row = 1;
            two.Col = 0;
            two.RowSpan = 1;
            two.ColSpan = 1;
            two.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
            three.Row = 1;
            three.Col = 1;
            three.RowSpan = 1;
            three.ColSpan = 1;
            three.Vis = Visibility.Visible;

            hidden1.Row = 0;
            hidden1.Col = 0;
            hidden1.RowSpan = 1;
            hidden1.ColSpan = 1;
            hidden1.Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void Show2Cells(Cell one, Cell two, Cell hidden1, Cell hidden2)
        {
            one.Row = 0;
            one.Col = 0;
            one.RowSpan = 1;
            one.ColSpan = 2;
            one.Vis = Visibility.Visible;
            two.Row = 1;
            two.Col = 0;
            two.RowSpan = 1;
            two.ColSpan = 2;
            two.Vis = Visibility.Visible;

            hidden1.Row = 0;
            hidden1.Col = 0;
            hidden1.RowSpan = 1;
            hidden1.ColSpan = 1;
            hidden1.Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
            hidden2.Row = 0;
            hidden2.Col = 0;
            hidden2.RowSpan = 1;
            hidden2.ColSpan = 1;
            hidden2.Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void Show1Cell(Cell one, Cell hidden1, Cell hidden2, Cell hidden3)
        {
            one.Row = 0;
            one.Col = 0;
            one.RowSpan = 2;
            one.ColSpan = 2;
            one.Vis = Visibility.Visible;

            hidden1.Row = 0;
            hidden1.Col = 0;
            hidden1.RowSpan = 1;
            hidden1.ColSpan = 1;
            hidden1.Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
            hidden2.Row = 0;
            hidden2.Col = 0;
            hidden2.RowSpan = 1;
            hidden2.ColSpan = 1;
            hidden2.Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
            hidden3.Row = 0;
            hidden3.Col = 0;
            hidden3.RowSpan = 1;
            hidden3.ColSpan = 1;
            hidden3.Vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public Cell Cell1 { get; set; }
        public Cell Cell2 { get; set; }
        public Cell Cell3 { get; set; }
        public Cell Cell4 { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thank you!